# How come this piece of code is working? It should crash due to buffer over-run but I am getting the output as "stackoverflow"

Tags: c

> Thisprogram should crash due to buffer overrun. But I am getting output as "stackoverflow". How?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *src;
    char dest[10];

    src = (char*)malloc(5);

    strcpy(src, "stackoverflow");
    printf("%s\n", src);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Writing past the end of the buffer you allocated gives undefined behaviour, but that doesn't mean it will crash... just that it might.  What happens will likely depend on what's immediately after your buffer.

Comment: Any question starting with *"How come this piece of code is working"* has a generic answer: *It is an undefined behavior.*

Comment: You'll have greater chance of success (i.e. failure) with `strcpy(dest, "much stackoverflow, wow");`.

Comment: As previously commented: just because you leave your car's parking brake off, does not mean that it *will* roll away. It depends on the circumstances. All you know for sure is there is no guarantee it will stay put.

Comment: @molbdnilo In that case also I am getting the same output. As others have mentioned, it has undefined behaviour so this may need not be crashed. Thanks!

Comment: So often writers seem disappointed that they wrote bad code, which did not immediately blow up in their face!

Comment: @WeatherVane Hi. I haven't written the code like this. Just wanted to make sure what could be the reason for this behaviour (in a particular scenario).

Comment: The tiniest slip in C code (where not seen by the compiler) can lead to: runaway code, which might crash; loop-bound code, which will just sit there; self-correcting errors; benign errors; memory corruption either locally or unrelated (but these days: not *other processes*); and so on. C offers little protection against all this, but there lies its power. Where it is critical, you check array bounds and data limits yourself at runtime, *especially* from user supplied data, and you test each function you write, as the work proceeds, with reasonable data and with corner cases.

Answer (score 4):

It does crash due to a buffer overrun.

The behaviour of your code is undefined as you are overrunning your buffer. You can't expect the behaviour to be in any way predictable.

It's difficult - and not required by the c standard - to issue an appropriate diagnostic in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Buffer overflows are not guaranteed to crash you: they cause undefined behavior. While a lot of platforms make the sequence of events that *may* or *may not* culminate in a crash rather predictable, one very important thing to consider is that the possible crash almost never happens at the same time that the damage is caused.

In a stack buffer overflow, possible crashes happens when you read the value of a variable that sat on the stack and was overflowed onto, or when you return from the function and the return address has been overwritten.

However, you're *not overflowing a stack buffer*: you're overflowing a heap buffer that you got from `malloc`. Typically, possible crashes there happens when you `free` that buffer or try to use a buffer that happened to be contiguous to it (there is, on purpose, no way to predict this). You allocate only one buffer and never free it, so you're not going to observe any problem from a small overflow.

In addition, I don't know any mainstream `malloc` implementation on desktops that returns blocks of less than 32 bytes, so even though you said `malloc(5)`, you probably have room for 32 bytes, so your short write is not overflowing on anything (although you **must not** rely on this).

The only case where an overflow will straight-up crash your program is if you overflow to a memory location that has not been assigned any meaning. For instance, if you do something like `memset('c', dest, 100000000)`, that will probably happen because you'll be busting out of the memory area that is reserved to the stack and there is probably nothing next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Copying to a buffer that is too small is undefined behavior; that doesn't necessarily mean it's guaranteed to crash.  For all we know those other bytes occupying the `"overflow\0"` part of your string aren't being used anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Because unless you are using some overrun-protection library/debugging tool, nothing will notice that you’re writing to memory you shouldn’t be. If you run this under `valgrind` it will display that you wrote to memory you shouldn’t have. But `malloc(5)` returns a pointer into a likely larger block of memory, so the chances of the buffer overflow resulting in trying to access an unmapped address is low. But if you had other `malloc()` calls, etc., you might notice the `"overflow"` part ending up in one of those other buffers—but it really depends on the implementation of `malloc()` and what code that overflow breaks won’t be deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer is allocated in the heap so your pointer src is pointing to buffer of char basicly of size 5 bytes because the size of char is 1 byte, however if the size of this allocated buffer + the added size by copying the string into this buffer doesn't exceed the size of the heap then it will work ,in the other hand if the total size try to overwrite an allocat memory by other pointer then you get the crash or the size exceed the heap size limitation you get the crash
As conclusion avoid this kind of code because you will get an unexpected behavior.